# How to select a node that has not attributes but has a specific value in XML

Tags: xml

I have stored a specific number in a variable ($ResId) from one part of an XML file, and I have the following in a different section.

```
<CalculatedWho>
  <ResourceId>85</ResourceId>
  <ResourceId>49</ResourceId>
  <ResourceId>43</ResourceId>
  <ResourceId>41</ResourceId>
</CalculatedWho>
```

If any of these match the number stored in the variable, I would then perform a particular task.  I've tried the following and several other things, but have yet to get it right.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//StrategyPool/Strategy">
  <xsl:if test="//StrategyPool/Strategy/CalculatedWho/ResourceId[text()=$ResId]" >
    <xsl:value-of select="StrategyName"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The problem is that the IF test never returns a value, though I know there are matches. I've also tried the following as the if test:

```
  <xsl:if test="/CalculatedWho/ResourceId[text()=$ResId]" >
```

and

Comment: seems ok , what is the issue you are facing ?

Answer (score 1):

Lacking a specific problem, something I immediately see as being wrong is that you don't need the "//StrategyPool/Strategy/" portion of the test in your xsl:if. The context node at that point is already a Strategy element. In addition, if you intend to select the value of StrategyName, ensure it is a sibling of the CalculatedWho node/immediate child of the Strategy node. Aside from that, depending on the value/type of $ResId you might get some weird coercion behavior.